# How to read msdn's t-sql syntax explanation?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, msdn

msdn.microsoft.com has tips, examples and explanantion on all kinds of t-sql code. But one does wrubs his head with the explanation given. For example, how to interpret the following (taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx)):

```
[ WITH <common_table_expression> [ ,...n ] ]

<common_table_expression>::=
    expression_name [ ( column_name [ ,...n ] ) ]
    AS
    ( CTE_query_definition )
```

How to read msdn's t-sql syntax explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See 'Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions (Transact-SQL)' on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx about the conventions for their syntax. Regarding the example:

`[ ] (brackets)`   Optional syntax items. Do not type the brackets.

`<label> ::=`     The name for a block of syntax. This convention is used to group and label sections of lengthy syntax or a unit of syntax that can be used in more than one location within a statement. Each location in which the block of syntax can be used is indicated with the label enclosed in chevrons: .

`[,...n]` Indicates the preceding item can be repeated n number of times. The occurrences are separated by commas.

A set is a collection of expressions, for example ; and a list is a collection of sets, for example .

`{ } (braces)` Required syntax items. Do not type the braces.